# Split and Discard right hand values

Tags: php

The while loop below returns an array as such

```
array(1) {
  ["Edge"]=>
  string(25) "10.333.192.41-222.96.253.91"
}
array(1) {
  ["Edge"]=>
  string(20) "133.94.4.1-44.0.1.250"
}
array(1) {
  ["Edge"]=>
  string(23) "222.94.1.1-233.123.20.82"
}
```

I want to throw away the righthand values and allow only the left hand values in the array. How may i accomplish this ? I used split but of course it doesn't discard. The delimiter to split is "-".

Comment: [`explode()`](http://www.php.net/explode) doesn't help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) to split your array values on a hyphen:

```
foreach ($array as $subarr) {
    list($left, $right) = explode('-', $subarr['Edge_ID'], 2);
    echo $left, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
10.333.192.41
133.94.4.1
222.94.1.1
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/103811)

Comment: should it be Edge instead of Edge_ID ?

Comment: @Hassan: It was `Edge_ID` when I answered. But still, the idea is same.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($arr as $val) {
    $pieces = explode('-', $val['Edge']);
    // $pieces[0] has left hand value
}
```